# Proving concavity of a function in multiple variables

Tags: machine-learning

How do I prove that $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{b}.\vec{x} - \log \left (1+e^{\vec{a}.\vec{x}} \right )$ is concave? where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are constant vectors.

My steps are as follows: The first term is a linear function in $\vec{x}$ so the first term is concave in $\vec{x}$.

If I can prove that the second term is concave in $\vec{x}$, then the sum of two concave functions is concave.

In order to show that the second term is concave, I have to show that $\log \left (1+e^{\vec{a}.\vec{x}} \right )$ is convex, right? How to do that?

Comment: How do you define the difference of a vector and a scalar?

Comment: I forgot the dot product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \log(1 + e^{a^\top x})$. It suffices to show that the Hessian is positive semi-definite.

The gradient is
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{-a^\top x}} a$$
and the Hessian is therefore
$$\frac{e^{-a^\top x}}{(1+e^{-a^\top x})^2} a a^\top.$$

The Hessian is a rank one matrix whose only nonzero eigenvalue is
$\frac{e^{-a^\top x}}{(1+e^{-a^\top x})^2} \|a\|^2 \ge 0$, so the Hessian is positive semi-definite.

Comment: The expression for your gradient seems wrong. Should it be = $\frac{e^{a^T x}}{1 + e^{a^T x} } a$ . Nevermind, I did not see the minus sign

Comment: @AdeelMahmood Multiply your expression by $e^{-a^\top x}/e^{-a^\top x}$ to obtain mine.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But shouldn't the numerator in the expression for Hessian have $e^{-a^T x}$? Thanks!

Comment: @AdeelMahmood yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the function $x \mapsto \log(1+e^x)$ twice to show that it is strictly convex.

If $f$ is convex and $g$ is affine then it is straightforward to show that $f \circ g$ is convex.

The map $x \mapsto \langle a, x \rangle$ is linear hence affine.